# Annotate the type of key and value but not the key name in a python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, annotations

I want to annotate the types of a key and the value in a dict. But I don't know the name key.

Most examples I can find are pointing to `TypedDict` from [PEP 589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/).

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Movie(TypedDict):
    name: str
    year: int

movie: Movie = {'name': 'Blade Runner',
                'year': 1982}
```

But this does annotate the type of specific key-values.

But I want to annoate a `dict` object (as return value) with this specifications

- The "name" of the keys are unknown.
- Number of keys is variable.
- All keys are of type `int`.
- All values are of type `list`.
- The value lists of variable length.
- The elements in the value lists are of type `int`.

Kind of this

```
dict{int: list[int]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to annotate only key and value types, but not define specific keys, then `TypedDict` isn't for you. In fact, you probably only want to use `dict[int, list[int]]`.

There are two layers to this:

- `dict[Type1, Type2]`: this annotation marks a dictionary where all keys are of `Type1` (in your case `int`) and all values of `Type2` (in your case `list[int]`)
- `list[Type]`: this specifies a `list` with only `Type` values (in your case `int`), this does not restrict the length of the list in any way. In fact the list may even be empty (yes, even `[]` is a valid `list[int]`)

To use it as a function's return value annotation, simply do it like this:

```
def myFunction() -> dict[int, list[int]]:
    return {
        0: [],
        10: [2, 5],
        11: [11],
        12: [2, 2, 3],
        13: [13],
        14: [2, 7],
    }
```

Here we have a sample function, that would return dictionary mapping a number to a list of it's prime factors. Notice that the keys can be any `int` and the values must be a `list` of `int` (empty list is also valid).